# Problems installing Postgresql 9.2 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install Postgres on my Ubuntu 13.04 system. In order to do so, I ran the following commands...

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-common -t raring
```

Both of which went fine. Then I tried to install the client by running...

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2
```

Which resulted in the following error message...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-9.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.2' has no installation candidate
```

The notion that 9.2 would be "obsoleted" seems very strange to me, as when I go to the Postgres site and check out the Ubuntu [installation page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/), I am told to run the command...

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.2
```

Comment: There is no `postgresql-9.2` package for Ubuntu 13.04. Please search [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&section=all&arch=any&keywords=postgresql-9.2&searchon=names).

Comment: This question belongs to http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try based on the following thread

https://serverfault.com/questions/514329/installing-postgres-on-ubuntu-package-not-available

> In Ubuntu official repositories only PostgreSQL 9.1 is available. That is why it couldn't >be found.
>
> In order to get PostgreSQL v9.2 in your VPS using apt you should follow the official >PostgreSQL procedure for Ubuntu found here
>
> It consists of adding PostgreSQL official repository as one of your repository source
>
> Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
>
> Insert this line deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
>
> Import the repository signing key wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media
> /keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
>
> Refresh your repositories cache sudo apt-get update
>
> Now you can simply do sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2